# Stop logging entire pyhive query to log file

Tags: python, logging, pyhive

I have a code pipeline where I'm using Pyhive to insert data into DB.

```
from pyhive import hive
def save_postprocess_data(postprocess_data):
    conn = hive.Connection(host="hostname", port=10000, username="username")
    curr = conn.cursor()
    insert = ""
    for i in range(postprocess_data.shape[0]):
    insert = insert + ",('%s','%d', '%d', '%s','%d','%s', '%.2f', '%s','%s','%d','%s')" % (postprocess_data.iloc[i,0],postprocess_data.iloc[i,1],postprocess_data.iloc[i,2],postprocess_data.iloc[i,3],postprocess_data.iloc[i,4],postprocess_data.iloc[i,5   ],postprocess_data.iloc[i,6],postprocess_data.iloc[i,7],postprocess_data.iloc[i,8],       postprocess_data.iloc[i,9],postprocess_data.iloc[i,10])
    insert_query = "insert into table table_name PARTITION (date) values"+ insert[1:]    
    curr.execute(insert_query)
    conn.close()
    return None
```

and, I get the entire query printed on the application log without even using logger

```
12/17/2018 07:59:21 AM USE `default`
12/17/2018 11:55:03 AM USE `default`
12/17/2018 11:55:03 AM insert into table table_name PARTITION (date) values("HUGE LIST OF VALUES")
```

I have the following config for logger

```
logging.basicConfig(filename=root_dir+'/application.log',format='%(asctime)s %(message)s', datefmt='%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p',level=logging.INFO)
```

problem is that i have around 30M records that needs to be inserted and the logger is flooded with the values from the query.

I would like to not log the entire query and only insert the following

```
logging.info("query successfully inserted %d values into the table",no_of_records)
```

Answer (score 2):

we can set different logging level for just pyhive library functions
by default it will print INFO which is the global level we have set for logger. 
And INFO would include the query , and that query is flooding the log file.

bu setting logging level for pyhive library we can stop the logger from printing the query in log.

`logging.getLogger('pyhive').setLevel(logging.CRITICAL)`